# Error when trying to set plotting font using Matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, fonts, plot

I'm running into a new error with Matplotlib 1.4.2 on Mac OS X (10.10.2) when trying to set the font to Times New Roman in my plot. Here is a MWE that gives an error:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.arange(0, 5, 0.1);
y = np.sin(x)
plt.plot(x, y)
plt.xlabel('X axis', fontname='Times New Roman')
```

If I try this, I receive `ValueError: failed to convert font family name to ASCII`. Adding the label without setting the font works fine.

This issue doesn't seem to be related to the specific font, because trying `Helvetica` or `Arial` causes the same issue.

I've tried deleting the font cache in `~/.matplotlib/fontList.cache` and then uninstalling and reinstalling Matplotlib, and get the same error. As I expect, when I check the font manager using `matplotlib.font_manager.OSXInstalledFonts()`, I see my full list of installed fonts.

I'm not sure what change triggered this error (it may be upgrading to 10.10.2), but I was able to set the font this way just fine up until I tried it today—I'm even trying to use previously working code.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem, when I used a fontdict.

I found a solution here: http://matplotlib.1069221.n5.nabble.com/matplotlib-error-ValueError-failed-to-convert-font-family-name-to-ASCII-td44202.html

Find your matplotlibrc file:

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.matplotlib_fname()
```

Open the file and change the graphics back-end, e.g.:
"backend: macosx" -> "backend: TkAgg"